# ERROR: fetching remote repo 'origin' in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

Can someone help me?

My erro in Jenkins using container docker:

```
Started by user Desenvolvimento Flash
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/FlashCTe
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url
ssh://ricardo_fernando@177.154.146.106:22/var/git/FlashCTe.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://ricardo_fernando@177.154.146.106:22/var/git/FlashCTe.git
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
> git fetch --tags --progress ssh://ricardo_fernando@177.154.146.106:22/var/git/FlashCTe.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from ssh://ricardo_fernando@177.154.146.106:22/var/git/FlashCTe.git
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:888)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1155)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1798)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress ssh://usename@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22/var/git/FlashCTe.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 143:
stdout: 
stderr: 
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2016)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1735)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:420)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:886)
... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

The container log:

```
Aug 25, 2018 9:31:22 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.AnonymousClassWarnings warn
WARNING: Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsScope$1 in file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/credentials/WEB-INF/lib/credentials.jar; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
Password: Password: Password:
```

[image: image my credentials]

[image: image using the credentials]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I used ssh credentials (with passphrase) to connect jenkins with my git repo. The problem was that I have launched the docker container with the -it flag.

I ran my docker container using the following command:

```
docker run -dit --name nameOfYourContainer --user $(id -u) -p 8080:8080  -v /tmp/jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock   -v "$HOME":/home   jenkinsci/blueocean
```

The problem comes from the -it flag which make Jenkins think it's run from a terminal and start asking for passphrase instead of using the one provided in Credentials settings. So I remove this flag and just use

```
docker run -d --name ...
```

To tackle your issue, it may be useful to display the logs provided by the container by running :

```
docker logs --details nameOfYourContainer
```

This is the command which points me to the right direction and here is the link where I found the solution:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20879?focusedCommentId=292906&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-292906